# Images Showing Up Differently in Chrome/Firefox vs Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-grid

I've been experimenting with CSS Grid and put together a layout that is okay in Chrome and Firefox, but when I try it in Safari the images are squished, particularly when the screen size shrinks. I made a code pen of this here:

https://codepen.io/jwolfe890/full/NzxjMx/

(Note, in the editor view in codepen the Safari images render appropriately, but they don't render appropriately in the Safari browser or full screen view)

As you can see in Safari, the images look like:

[image]

While in Chrome/Firefox other browsers it looks like:

[image]

I'm using min-height and max-height in the css, which may be rendering the images differently between the browsers. How can I achieve a consistent rendering of images across browsers?

CSS File:

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
    height: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the height 100% for the first image improved the issued, but there is still a slight disparity in that the pictures now slightly don't fill the grid trac:

```
img:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
    height: 100%; <--- REMOVED THIS
}
```

However, it's still perplexing to me why height 100% would render the images differently across browsers.

Comment: because 100% of what in this case?

Comment: in safari i guess it's reading it as 100% of the image, and in chrome/firefox 100% of the grid space

Comment: which is frustrating because it won't fill the entire grid space without the 100%. i guess my question should have been how to responsively fill a css grid space with an image across all three major browsers.

Comment: well I cannot give you the exact explanation as I am missing something ... but wait for the CSS-grid Guru to come ;)

Comment: i think this might be an area where flexbox might be necessary. css grid might be cross browser compliant now, but it's still hindered by browser differences such as these